# Correct term for tilting a window

Tags: перевод, выбор-слова

*I opened the window* I'd say like this: *Я открыл окно*. How to say

- ***I tilted the window.* e. g. I opened the window using its tilting mechanism (Image A)?**
- ***The window is tilted.* (Image B)?**

PS: Please both aspects.

> Image A - (coralwindows.co.uk)
> [image: tilting a window]
>
> Image B - (tiltco.net)
> [image: tilted window]

Comment: I'd say «приоткрыл» for the 1st sentence, I doubt there's an exact word for that way of opening windows.

Comment: I would generally say "открыл окно" even when the windows is tilted that way. "Приоткрыл окно" would also be ok, although it is less frequently used and may also be confused with [this way](http://www.dostupokna.ru/upload/medialibrary/417/417829105134cb8c91865f6aecf837d6.jpg) of letting the air in.

Comment: There is also an archaic word "отворить"/"приотворить" which sounds surprisingly intuitive to mean "tilt a window" for me in the first case: "Я приотворил окно". This may be subjective though.

Comment: Please consider accepting any of the answers!

Answer (score 6):

As Yellow Sky already answered, first picture can be described as "приоткрыть окно", but this leaves uncertainity here, since you can leave a window in this 'tilted stable position', or open it similar to half-open door.

Action for the second image would be "открыть окно на проветривание" ("окно открыто на проветривание"), unfortunately I am not aware of any simpler wordage. "Приоткрытое окно" would also have two possible meanings - tilted one and "half-open".

In commercial descriptions of such window function it is called "режим проветривания".

Answer (score 3):

***I tilted the window. e. g. I opened the window using its tilting mechanism (Image A)?***

Regarding noun in use: for ventilation we may use window, but you should probably use name of small or medium ventilation sections of windows (**форточка** is a small ventilation window. It usually spans the frame of one window pane and opens on hinges independently of the whole window. Size is about 50x50 cm or less. If it is bigger and elongated, it is called rather **фрамуга** - horizontal or vertical part of window, but NOT section of window, size is about 1m in length). Window-word (окно) is usually reserved for big windows.

You should know that doing so is not called tilting in Russia(n).

Tilting is not customary to Russian windows and common expression for exact this type of window does not exist. If you say something literally. similar to "tilting" you will not be understood. We either **открываем** (literally open, quite wide) or  **приоткрываем** (open ajar, half way).

***The window is tilted. (Image B)?***
I think the best fit is ***окно приоткрыто/форточка приоткрыта*** It does not say whether it is locked or not.

So you basically can not say it is "tilted" but use more generalized "open"/"half-open" word.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "фрамуга"  This word was more popular in the 60-s, but seem to disappear nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

The tilt-and-turn mechanism is called *поворотно-откидной механизм* in Russian.

If you want to specify which way exactly is the window open, you use *створка отворена* "the sash is turn open" or *створка откинута* "the sash is tilt open".

It's also OK to use synecdoches *отворить окно* or *откинуть окно*, though, strictly speaking, those verbs only apply to the sash (*створка*) which is just a part of the window (*окно*). However, in everyday speech usage like this is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Though in casual speach I really don't think one would be using such a specifications as "Я открыл окно вертикально", "Окно открыто вертикально". Sounds like phrase or directions from some manual. Except for case you just need to clarify that the window is tilted and not wide-opened. In any other case there's really  no need in such a detail, you can just state the fact  я открыл (opened) or я приоткрыл  (half-opened). I guess that the tilting mechanism in a window kind of imitates/replaces window leaf (форточка). So as an option maybe you can say "открыть окно как форточку"... As for "на проветривание" part - sounds kind of obvious and excessive, why else would anyone open windows?))

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is said in comments about what is actually "приоткрой" de-facto "приоткрыть" is used for designating exactly this action. It usually depends on context which action actually meant - regular "приоткрыть" or vertical "приоткрыть". When context is not enough, one can say something like:

"Приоткрой ручкой вверх", "приоткрой вот так вот" (and showing with gesture) - people when talking tend to avoid using lengthy words like "вертикально", which, of course, is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

As Artemix pointed out in his answer, window tilting function is called "режим проветривания".

From my own experience (I'm Russian, have a window that opens that way at home and used to have one at my workplace too) people usually say "открой окно на проветривание" or (rarely) "откинь окно/форточку" when they ask somebody to tilt a window open.

Neither of these are universally understood nor "official" terms for tilting a window open though, so you might have to add "ручкой вверх" (the handle upwards) if people don't understand what you mean (happens to me about 3 times out of 10).

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding all the boring nuances - "я ПРИоткрыл окно", "приоткрытое окно" would be absolutely normal and no one will said that it is not acceptable or is not "native way to say it".

Answer (score 0):

I would also mention the variant "***вертикально***":

- "**Я открыл окно *вертикально***"
- "**Окно открыто *вертикально***"

This is the variant used in my surroundings.

The variant "***на проветривание***" is also widely used but often it specializes that the window is "***приоткрыто***" just a bit, when the handle is near 45 degrees:
[image]

Thus,

- "**Я открыл окно *на проветривание***"
- "**Окно *на проветривании***".

It really may be just a local use but it's common in many places over Tomsk and Krasnoyarsk regions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a more descriptive sentence:

**Oн растворил фрамугу, так что образовалась щель по её верху**

If you want to emphasize the slightness of tilting,

**Он слегка повернул фрамугу, открыв щель по её верху**